# Get download count via download attribute with Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm doing a project with Django, like a music player, this is my models:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    """Model representing a song"""
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, help_text=_('Enter a song name'))
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='cover_image')
    content = models.FileField(upload_to='songs')
    artist = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Check this box to make the song public')
    )
```

since I already configured the uploaded folder and all, all I have to do in my templates is adding the download attribute to the  tag and it will download file for the user

```
<a href="/media/{{ i.content }}" download="{{ i.name }}" type="video/mp4">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Download Song </button>
          </a>
```

This works flawlessly, however it proves to be quite difficult if I want to get the download count for the song.
I'm thinking of giving it the tag an onclick attribute so when I click the download button it will trigger a javascript function to send a hidden form to views to increment the downloads value. However this I think is quite convoluted so I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: if you serve from static it can be problematic I think in that case you can use last access of a file os.stat (see st_atime). I suggest you to serv your files from a custom link for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to track the download count for a song in Django.

- One approach is to use a separate model to track the download count and update it whenever a download occurs.

Create a new model to track the download count:

```py
class Download(models.Model):
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Update your view to handle the download request and increment the download count:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def download_song(request, song_id):
    song = get_object_or_404(Song, pk=song_id)
    
    # Increment the download count
    download, created = Download.objects.get_or_create(song=song)
    download.count += 1
    download.save()
    
    # Return the file for download
    file_path = song.content.path
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type='application/octet-stream')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
        return response
```

Update your template to call the download_song view when the download button is clicked

```
<a href="{% url 'download_song' i.id %}" download="{{ i.name }}" type="video/mp4">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Download Song</button>
</a>
```

Add a URL pattern for the download_song view in your urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import download_song

urlpatterns = [
    # Other URL patterns
    path('download/<int:song_id>/', download_song, name='download_song'),
]
```

- Another approach to track the download count for a song in Django is to use Django's built-in `middleware`.

```
class DownloadCountMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Check if the response is a file download
        if response.get('Content-Disposition', '').startswith('attachment'):
            song_id = request.GET.get('song_id')
            if song_id:
                song = get_object_or_404(Song, pk=song_id)
                song.download_count += 1
                song.save()

        return response
```

Register the middleware class in your Django settings

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # Other middleware classes
    'yourapp.middleware.DownloadCountMiddleware',
]
```

Update your template to pass the song ID as a query parameter when the download button is clicked

```
<a href="/media/{{ i.content }}?song_id={{ i.id }}" download="{{ i.name }}" type="video/mp4">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Download Song</button>
</a>
```